# Documentation generation tools that parse only comments blocks

Tags: documentation-generator, parser

I am looking for documentation generation tools that only interpret the comment blocks when generating code documentation. It means that, to some extent, the tool does not depend on the programming language even if I need to declare everything.

One example is [YUIDoc](https://yui.github.io/yuidoc/) that parse ["comment blocks, not source code"](https://yui.github.io/yuidoc/syntax/index.html). But the project seems lost support in it [github page](https://github.com/yui/yuidoc).

The output could be in any format (HTML, XML, JSON, etc ), but I would prefer a tool that produces an output with more semantically readable structure (e.g. XML, JSON ).

Comment: And what do you use that information for?

Comment: Extract some metrics and relational information about the code in software I'm writing. Maybe I could do it with other tools, but I want to do some operations from the information given by the programmer in comments.

Comment: And I'm not searching for any specific information extraction by now. The only tool  I know that met my requirements is YUIDoc. Maybe other tools could provide syntax, tags, and information that I am not expecting.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I was just considering that you have an XY-issue, where you think analyzing comments would be a solution for a totally diffferent problem. Technically, I think such a tool should be possible, especially if you're willing to configure much. Yet, I don't know any out-of-the-box tool.